# Unable to pass parameter in action attribute of form elment

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I am using below code(snippet) to pass struts parameter as a part of url in action attribute of a form element

```
<html:form enctype="multipart/form-data" 
           action="/saveInstr.do?org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN="<%=session.getAttribute(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY)%> 
           method="POST">
```

This gets compiled but when I try to run the code...it renders below error JSPG0060E: Invalid jsp syntax [].

Note: I am using Struts 1.3, JAVA J2EE, Webshpere server

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if it's the same issue I once had. Jsp seems not to like mixed parameters ("..."+JAVA-expression). Try it this way:

```
<html:form enctype="multipart/form-data" 
           action=<%="/saveInstr.do?org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN="+session.getAttribute(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY)%> 
           method="POST">
```

Another possible issue would be, that you try to pass other parameters too (which should throw a syntax error).